# How to generate PDF from currently submitted InfoPath form from a Sharepoint Library

Tags: sharepoint-2013, infopath, sharepoint-workflow

I have a SharePoint Library and I want to generate and send PDF of the InfoPath form in an email when form is submitted to the SharePoint library.

Is there any way to do it using workflow or any other way to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: What kind of form, an InfoPath Form or a List Item 'Form'. BTW, you may want to try SharePoint.StackExchange.com

Comment: It is an InfoPath form.

Comment: In that case Google for "infopath converter for sharepoint". It shows several solutions including one that I worked on.

Answer (score 1):

I've done this before, I used an open source dll, unfortunately I forgot the name of the dll.
but Yes, you can do that using workflow or event receiver.
The infopath form is not converted directly to pdf,
first, the infopath will be converted to html,
then html converted to pdf.
That's how I achieved to convert infopath to pdf

Answer (score 0):

there is no direct conversion way. think about recreating form in PDF from scratch. It could be cheaper and faster. If you plan to use PDF forms with your SharePoint environment, PDF Share Forms solution is a must have for you. More info on www.pdfshareforms.com

(I work for PDF Share Forms)